# Clover maxAggregatedStatements for maven plugin

Tags: ant, maven-2, clover

I'm currently trying to configure some method exclusions in my projects sonar configuration (the methods being excluded are irrelevant to my question).
I have clover configured through the maven plugin.

From my research, I found that as part of defining your context for ant, there are a number of options available besides just the regex method signature to match on. My specific interest is in the parameter "maxAggregatedStatements".

Does this functionality exist for the maven plugin? So far all my searching hasn't produced anything, so at present, I can only match on the method signature.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently (Clover 3.2.0) there is no such option in the maven-clover2-plugin. There is a feature request reported, so you can track a progress here: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CLOV-1173 - it's on the road map, scheduled for year 2014.

As a workaround you could use a custom report descriptor. See

https://docs.atlassian.com/maven-clover2-plugin/latest/clover-mojo.html#reportDescriptor

and

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/Creating+custom+reports